# TypeError: _this.props.data(...) is undefined in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

**I am trying to perform CRUD operation on material-table along with server-side pagination and searching for this I am using remote data with material-table but facing props data error
I have tried this by reaping it in resolver but facing the same error**

```
<MaterialTable
          title="Sensors"
          options={{
            rowStyle: (x) => {
              if (x.tableData.id % 2 != 1) {
                return { backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2" };
              }
            },
            exportButton: {
              csv: true,
              pdf: true,
            },
          }}
          columns={columns}
          data={handedata}
          components={{
            Toolbar: (props) => (
              <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#e8eaf5" }}>
                <MTableToolbar {...props} />
              </div>
            ),
          }}
        />

function handedata(query) {
axios
  .post(
    `/info/getAllSensorsWithDownTime?page=${query.page + 1}&limit=${
      query.pageSize
    }&start_date=${" "}&end_date=${" "}`,
    { arrayOfsensorIds: [] }
  )
  .then((result) => {
    const { data } = result.data;

    return {
      data: data.sensor.map((o) => ({
        ...o.info,
        downtime: o.downTime,
      })),
      page: data.metadata[0].page - 1,
      totalCount: data.metadata[0].total,
    };
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("here is error ", err);
    return {
      data: [],
      page: 0,
      totalCount: 0,
    };
  });
```

}